# Subarray with given sum time limit exceeded

Tags: javascript, arrays, sub-array

Given an unsorted array A of size N that contains only non negative integers, find a continuous sub-array that adds to a given number S and return the left and right index(1-based indexing) of that subarray.

In case of multiple subarrays, return the subarray indexes which come first on moving from left to right.

Note:- You have to return an ArrayList consisting of two elements left and right. In case no such subarray exists return an array consisting of element -1.

Input:
N = 5, S = 12
A[] = {1,2,3,7,5}
Output: 2 4
Explanation: The sum of elements
from 2nd position to 4th position
is 12.

Input:
N = 10, S = 15
A[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
Output: 1 5
Explanation: The sum of elements
from 1st position to 5th position
is 15.

```
subarraySum(arr, n, s)
    {
    let sum = 0
    let i=0
    let j=0
    while(i<=j){
        if (sum <= s) {
             sum += arr[j];
            if (sum === s) {
                return [i + 1,j + 1].join("")
                break;
            }
            j++;
         } else {
            i++;
            sum = arr[i];
            j = i + 1;
         } 
        }
        if(sum < s || sum > s){
          return -1
        }
    }

can someone optimize this code i am getting time limit exceeded
```

Comment: You're asking for optimization and exceeding time limits, but you have offered no requirements and the inputs you provided should run trivially, so I suspect you're trying to get us to do a coding challenge for you.  If you wanted an answer you need to post the *full* input that is taking too long and the time requirement it needs to run in.